# How to describe a rotation of $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Tags: notation, integer-lattices

I was recently looking at random walks in 2 dimensions, and was able to simplify a problem involving the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by rotating it by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians, as below:
[image]

Each point on the new grid is represented with $(x,y)$, and the grid being diagonal also ensures that $x+y=2n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

How would I describe this space in such a way as to be able to do mathematics with it?

Comment: You mean $\Bbb Z\big[\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2},\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}\big]$?

Comment: That might be similar to what I mean. Does the notation refer to the set of values on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ representable as $n\frac{1+i}{2}+m\frac{1-i}{2}$ for $\left\{n,m\right\}\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, almost. The square roots are important.